# Person speaking truth and a dice is thrown , probability problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

A person speaks the truth 8 times out of 10 times. A die is rolled. He reports that is was 5. What is the probability that it was actually 5.

A = A speaks the truth.
F = 5 appears

P(A) = 8/10 ,P(F) = 1/6

$$P(F|A) = \frac{P(A|F).P(F)}{P(A|F).P(F) + P(-A|F).P(F)}$$

Is this the correct way of doing this? I am really confused. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think we need an additional independence assumption (or several) to be able to make progress on this?  Seems underspecified.

Comment: I am making an assumption that it is mutually exclusive and exhaustive event @user3716267

Comment: The question is what number the person will give if he doesn't tell the truth.  Does he randomly choose among the incorrect numbers with equal probability?  So you need to know the probability that the person will say $5$ if the die roll results in a number different from $5$ and he lies.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that if the person lies, he randomly selects among the $5$ wrong numbers with equal probability.  In that case, the probability that the roll really was a $5$ is $0.8$.

Let's perform $30$ trials.  In $5$ of those trials, the die will come up $5$ and in $4$ of those $5$ trials, the person will truthfully report $5$.

In the other $25$ trials, the die will come up some number other than $5$.  In $5$ of those $25$ trials, the person will lie.  In $1$ of those $5$ trials, the lie will be a false report that the die roll was a $5$.

Thus, in $5$ trials, the person will report that the die roll was a $5$.  He'll be telling the truth in $4$ of those $5$ trials.  Thus, given that the report is a $5$, the probability that the die roll was actually a $5$ is $0.8$.